# Python: Check if dataframe column contain string type

Tags: python, dataframe

I want check if columns in a dataframe consists of strings so I can label them with numbers for machine learning purposes. Some columns consists of numbers, I dont want to change them. Columns example can be seen below:

```
TRAIN FEATURES
  Age              Level  
  32.0              Silver      
  61.0              Silver  
  66.0              Silver      
  36.0              Gold      
  20.0              Silver     
  29.0              Silver     
  46.0              Silver  
  27.0              Silver
```

Thank you=)

Answer (score 24):

4 years since the creation of this question and I believe there's still not a definitive answer.

I don't think strings were ever considered as a first class citizen in Pandas (even >= 1.0.0). As an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'str': ['a', 'b', 'c', None],
    'hete': [1, 2.0, datetime.datetime.utcnow(), None]
})

string_series = df['str']
print(string_series.dtype)
print(pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(string_series.dtype))

heterogenous_series = df['hete']
print(heterogenous_series.dtype)
print(pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(heterogenous_series.dtype))
```

prints

```
object
True
object
True
```

so although `hete` does not contain any explicit strings, it is considered as a string series.

After reading [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html), I think the only way to make sure a series contains only strings is:

```
def is_string_series(s : pd.Series):
    if isinstance(s.dtype, pd.StringDtype):
        # The series was explicitly created as a string series (Pandas>=1.0.0)
        return True
    elif s.dtype == 'object':
        # Object series, check each value
        return all((v is None) or isinstance(v, str) for v in s)
    else:
        return False


print(is_string_series(string_series))
print(is_string_series(heterogenous_series))
```

prints

```
True
False
```

### April 2023 Update

It seems like the [recently released Pandas 2](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html) behaves the same way (the test script above produces the same output with Python 3.11).

Answer (score 16):

Notice that the **above answers will include DateTime, TimeStamp, Category** and other datatypes.

Using `object` is more restrictive (although I am not sure if other `dtypes` would also of `object` dtype):

1. Create the dataframe:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame({
       'a': ['a','b','c','d'], 
       'b': [1, 'b', 'c', 2], 
       'c': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4], 
       'd': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A'], 
       'e': pd.to_datetime('today')})
   df['d'] = df['d'].astype('category')
   ```

That will look like this:

```
   a  b    c  d          e
0  a  1  NaN  A 2018-05-17
1  b  b  2.0  B 2018-05-17
2  c  c  3.0  B 2018-05-17
3  d  2  4.0  A 2018-05-17
```

2. You can check the types calling `dtypes`:

   ```
   df.dtypes

   a            object
   b            object
   c           float64
   d          category
   e    datetime64[ns]
   dtype: object
   ```
3. You can list the strings columns using the `items()` method and filtering by `object`:

   ```
   > [ col  for col, dt in df.dtypes.items() if dt == object]
   ['a', 'b']
   ```
4. Or you can use select_dtypes to display a dataframe with only the strings:

   ```
   df.select_dtypes(include=[object])
      a  b
   0  a  1
   1  b  b
   2  c  c
   3  d  2
   ```

Comment: Here's a more concise (and likely to be faster) way to do step 3: `df.columns[df.dtypes=='object']`

Answer (score 14):

I use a 2-step approach: first to determine if `dtype==object`, and then if so, I got the first row of data to see if that column's data was a string or not.

```
c = 'my_column_name'
if df[c].dtype == object and isinstance(df.iloc[0][c], str):
    # do something
```

Comment: Assumes no NAs in your dataset.

Comment: If you are doing some kind of a filter on a df filter with contains then : .str.contains(srch_string, na=False) should be used.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, its possible. You use [`dtype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dtype.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a','b','c','d']})
if df['a'].dtype != np.number:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

You can also select your columns by dtype using [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

```
df_subset = df.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number])
# Now apply you can label encode your df_subset
```

Comment: this will include DateTimes and other objects dtypes

Comment: This is a test if a column is *not* a number, as @toto_tico mentions, there's a lot more possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

With Pandas 1.0 [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) was introduced. When a column was not explicitly created as [`StringDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html#pandas.StringDtype) it can be easily converted.

`pd.StringDtype.is_dtype` will then return `True` for wtring columns. Even when they contain NA values.

For old and new style strings the complete series of checks could be something like this:

```
def has_string_type(s: pd.Series) -> bool:
    if pd.StringDtype.is_dtype(s.dtype):
        # StringDtype extension type
        return True

    if s.dtype != "object":
        # No object column - definitely no string
        return False

    try:
        s.str
    except AttributeError:
        return False

    # The str accessor exists, this must be a String column
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Scratch'N'Purr's answer:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a','b','c','d'], 'b': [1, 'b', 'c', 2], 'c': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4]})
>>> df 
   a  b    c
0  a  1  NaN
1  b  b  2.0
2  c  c  3.0
3  d  2  4.0

>>> dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] != np.number, list(zip(df.columns, df.dtypes))))
{'a': dtype('O'), 'b': dtype('O')}
```

So I've added some columns with mixed types. You can see that the `filter` + `dict` approach yields key: value mappings of which columns have dtypes outside of the bounds of `np.number`. This ought to work well at scale. You could also try coercing each column to a specific type (e.g. `int`) and then catch the `ValueError` exception when you can't convert a string column to `int`. Lots of ways to do this.

Comment: this will include DateTimes and other objects dtypes

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the only sure fire way to know what types are there is to check the values, then you can do an assertion to see if it's what you expect.

The below function will get the dtypes of each value in a column, drop duplicates and then cast to a list so you can view/interact with it. This will let you deal with mixed types, objects and NAs the way you wish (of course np.nan is of type float but I leave such things to the interested reader)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   "col2": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                   "col3": [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
                   })

print(df.dtypes.to_dict())
# {'col1': dtype('int64'), 'col2': dtype('O'), 'col3': dtype('O')}

def true_dtype(df): # You could add a column filter here too
    return {col: df[col].apply(lambda x: type(x)).unique().tolist() for col in df.columns}

true_types = true_dtype(df)
print(true_types)
# {'col1': [<class 'int'>], 'col2': [<class 'str'>], 'col3': [<class 'list'>]}

print(true_types['col2'] == [str])
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return a list of column name whose dtype is string(object in this case)

```
#let df be your dataframe     
df.columns[df.dtypes==object].tolist()
```