# Check if ENTIRE pandas object column is a string

Tags: python, pandas

How can I check if a column is a string, or another type (e.g. int or float), even though the dtype is object?

(Ideally I want this operation vectorised, and not `applymap` checking every row...)

```py
import io
# American post code
df1_str = """id,postal
1,12345
2,90210
3,"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df1_str))
df1["postal"] = df1["postal"].astype("O")  # is an object (of type float due to the null row 3)
```

```
# British post codes
df2_str = """id,postal
1,EC1
2,SE1
3,W2"""
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df2_str))
df2["postal"] = df2["postal"].astype("O")  # is an object (of type string)
```

Both `df1` and `df2` return `object` when doing `df["postal"].dtype`

- However, `df2` has `.str` methods, e.g. `df2["postal"].str.lower()`, but `df1` doesn't.
- Similarly, `df1` can have mathematical operations done to it, e.g. `df1 * 2`

---

This is different to other SO questions. who ask if there are strings inside a column (and not the WHOLE column). e.g:

- [Python: Check if dataframe column contain string type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049545/python-check-if-dataframe-column-contain-string-type)
- [Check if string is in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944577/check-if-string-is-in-a-pandas-dataframe)
- [Check pandas dataframe column for string type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151010/check-pandas-dataframe-column-for-string-type)

Comment: Try: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60955/how-to-check-all-values-in-particular-column-has-same-data-type-or-not However, I usually use pd.to_numeric without huge performance issues

Comment: It would be cool if the pandas devs included an optional argument in df.info() for this in the future. It could show the value counts of each data type within each column and again would be an optional argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.api.types.infer_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.infer_dtype.html):

```
>>> pd.api.types.infer_dtype(df2["postal"])
'string'
>>> pd.api.types.infer_dtype(df1["postal"])
'floating'
```

From the docs:

> **Efficiently** infer the type of a passed val, or list-like array of values. Return a string describing the type.